# Request log parser - Text parsing

Tags: java, awk, groovy, text-parsing, processing-efficiency

I have to parse a request log that has following structure

```
07/Dec/2017:18:15:58 +0100 [293920] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:58 +0100 [293920] <- 200 text/html 5ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:58 +0100 [293921] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:58 +0100 [293921] <- 200 image/png 39ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293922] -> HEAD URL HTTP/1.0
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293922] <- 401 - 1ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293923] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293923] <- 200 text/html 178ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293924] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293924] <- 200 text/html 11ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293925] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293925] <- 200 text/html 7ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293926] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293926] <- 200 text/html 16ms
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293927] -> GET URL HTTP/1.1
07/Dec/2017:18:15:59 +0100 [293927] <- 200 text/html 8ms
```

The output should link two lines in this log based on the number between square brackets.
The goal is to extract information from this logfile with other data processing software packages. 
I want to extract useful information using a csv file.
The structure of the csv file should be as follows.

```
startTimestamp,endTimestamp,requestType/responseCode,URL/typ,responsetime

07/Dec/2017:18:15:58,07/Dec/2017:18:15:58,GET,200,URL,text/html,5ms
```

I have made a groovyScript that does the trick but it is terribly slow.

I know i can make some improvements but would like your ideas. Some of you probably have tackled this problem in the past.

The response does not always follow the request.
Not every request gets a response (or is not logged due to server restart)

The log files can be from 70mb up to 300 mb. My groovyScript takes a ridiculous long time.

I know there are good and fast solutions in the unix terminal with awk and sort. But have no experience with this.

Thanks in advance for your help

Here is the code I already have
possible improvements

1) use map with the key being the number for faster search and less parsing

2) don't go over the backlog list for every line

```
def logFile = new File("../request.log")
def outputfile = new File(logFile.parent, logFile.name + ".csv")
def backlog = new ArrayList<String>()
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()


outputfile.withPrintWriter { writer ->
    logFile.withReader { Reader reader ->
        reader.eachLine { String line ->
            Iterator<String> it = backlog.iterator()
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String bLine = it.next()
                String[] lineSplit = line.split(" ")
                if (bLine.contains(lineSplit[2])) {
                    String[] bLineSplit = bLine.split(" ")
                    output.append(bLineSplit[0] + "," + lineSplit[0] + "," + bLineSplit[4] + "," + lineSplit[4] + "," + bLineSplit[5] + "," + lineSplit[5] + "," + lineSplit[6] + "\r\n")
                    //writer.println(outputline)
                    it.remove()
                }
            }
            backlog.add(line)
        }
    }
    writer.println(output)
    if (!backlog.isEmpty()) {
    }
    backlog.each { String line ->
        writer.println(line)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one-liner:

```
sort -k 3,3 request.log | awk 'BEGIN { print "startTimestamp;endTimestamp;requestType;responseCode;URL;typ;responsetime"; split("", request); split("", response) } $4 == "->" { printLine(); split($0, request); split("", response) } $4 == "<-" { split($0, response) } END { printLine() } function printLine() { if (length(request)) { print request[1] ";" response[1] ";" request[5] ";" response[5] ";" request[6] ";" response[6] ";" response[7] } }'
```

As multi-liner:

```
sort -k 3,3 request.log | awk '
    BEGIN {
        print "startTimestamp;endTimestamp;requestType;responseCode;URL;typ;responsetime"
        split("", request)
    }
    $4 == "->" {
        printLine()
        split($0, request)
        split("", response)
    }
    $4 == "<-" {
        split($0, response)
    }
    END {
        printLine()
    }
    function printLine() {
        if (length(request)) {
            print request[1] ";" response[1] ";" request[5] ";" response[5] ";" request[6] ";" response[6] ";" response[7]
        }
    }'
```

Comment: This is genius and at the same time I have a hard time reading the awk statement, because it's the first time I see a awk script like this.
there are some issues however. 
This is because the URL contains comma's and this makes a bad csv file ;)
I tried to change the delimiter in your script to a semicolon instead of comma's

this improved the result a lot. but stil there is something weird.

some lines don't have a response time. Is this because there simply was no response for this request? This is an example of a bad output line:
{ 07/Dec/2017:00:29:49  GET  <URL>}

Comment: My question is actually. How do you match, in your script, a certain request with a certain response? Because in the source file the request and response don't always come right after each other.
Should I sort the file on the number between square brackets ( the third element in the entry) before I execute this script?

Comment: Yes, that line looks like only request fields are set, response was not found. The sort should match the lines together, was bullshit of course, because it sorted by date. Now it sorts by request ID first, and only after that by date, so now it should work better.

Comment: I've also added quotes around the URL because the URL field tends to contain comma's semicolons or whatever delimiter i choose.
When the url is between quotes it is treated like text. 
Thanks a lot! This answers my question.
Also the speed is amazing. parsed a 180mb file in about 10 seconds